# xslt1.0 variable problem

Tags: xslt

I have the following template:

```
<xsl:template name="theday">
    <xsl:param name="thisday" />

    <xsl:variable name='holiday' select='foo'/><!-- made this static for testing -->

    <td class="{$holiday}"> <!-- no value is inserted in class -->

        <a>
            <xsl:attribute name='href'><xsl:value-of
                select="concat('?date=',$thisday)" /></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="date:day-in-month($thisday)" />
        </a>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

I expect to get HTML something like this:

```
<td class="foo">
  <a href="?date=2009-11-02">2</a>
</td>
```

Unfortunately, I get:

```
<td class="">
  <a href="?date=2009-11-02">2</a>
</td>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:variable name='holiday'>foo</xsl:variable>
```

or

```
<xsl:variable name='holiday' select="'foo'"/>
```

How it works: the `select` attribute expects an *expression* to be evaluated; since you probably don't have a `foo` element at context, it is resolved as an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `<xsl:variable name='holiday' select='foo'/>` selects the nodelist 'foo' (which is empty)  not the string foo. If you had xml

```
<a>
  <foo>B</foo>
</a>
```

then (when currently at `a`) `<xsl:variable name='holiday' select='foo'/>` would give 'B'.

To fix this specify a constant:

```
<xsl:variable name='holiday' select="'foo'"/>
```